# GPS in windows mobile

Tags: windows-mobile, gps

How would I  go about obtaining the GPS cordinates in a windows mobile application? The sample app that comes with the SDK doesnt seem to work. I also have the wm 6.5 SDK which I heard had GPS stuff but I cant find it. Let me know if you have any good examples.

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/468666/access-gps-functionality-in-winmobile-phones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go with [GPS.Net](http://gps3.codeplex.com/).  It's an excellent library, very easy to use and compatible with a whole pile of hardware implementations.

We used it for Windows Mobile and Windows Xp/Vista versions of an application.

Answer (score 1):

As of WCE 5.0 microsoft includes a gps intermediate driver which sits in front of the devices gps device and provides an api for retrieving position information.

Main api docs are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms850332.aspx)

The api you need to use to get a position is documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms889503.aspx)

Managed code docs and examples [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb158708.aspx)

IIRC you may need to set up the driver on some devices, i think its a case of telling it which com port the gps device is on. Also I seem to remember that you can set it up on the emulator and give it a track log file and it will return positions based on the contents of the file, for testing purposes.