# How to use GPS Intermediate Driver?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, gps, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I'm exploring on how to connect to GPS on Windows Mobile using VB.net. (Compact framework)

Most of the result that I found is using  [*GPS Intermediate Driver*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468666/access-gps-functionality-in-winmobile-phones) . but this seems not solve my problem(or perhaps I just don't understand it?)

Besides, I found that there is something like `gpsapi.dll` in which I think I can add as a reference. But where can I get this?

I've read [article:using the managed GPS sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb158708.aspx) too, but it seems only for `C`?

Please guide me / correct me if I'm wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it is for C#. And the download for the Windows Mobile 6.5.3 Developer Tool Kit
 is here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=5389

Read the steps in the article link carefully:

Find the samples folder, compile the sample, grab the generated dll, import into your solution as a reference, put in the imports directive and you should be there.

Comment: I already have the Windows Mobile 6.5.3 DTK but I found no `gpsapi.dll` neither any GPS tools for vb.net.

Comment: read the steps in the article link you provided carefully: find the samples folder, compile the sample, grab the generated dll, import into your solution as a reference, put in the imports directive and you should be there.

Comment: I managed to get the `using Microsoft.WindowsMobile.Samples.Location` and add as a reference. thanks! edit your answer with your comment and I'll choose it as the best answer. :D